# Prim's algorithm for finding the minimum spanning tree

Tags: python, graph

So I was coding [Prim's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim's_algorithm) for practice and this is what I wrote. It works for finding the weight of the minimum spanning tree (MST) but I'm wondering if the loop I am doing to add the the edges in the frontier to the minheap is optimal.

```
import heapq
from collections import defaultdict
g = defaultdict(list)
weight = 0 
connected = set([])
pq = []

#n is the number of nodes m is the number of edges
n, m = [int(x) for x in raw_input().split(" ")]
#create adjacency list from inputs of the form "vertex1 vertex2 weight"
for _ in xrange(m):
    a, b, w = [int(x) for x in raw_input().split(" ")]
    g[a].append((w, b))
    g[b].append((w, a))

start = int(raw_input())
connected.add(start)
for tup in g[start]:
    heapq.heappush(pq, tup)
while pq:
    w, b = heapq.heappop(pq)
    if b not in connected:
        weight += w
        connected.add(b)
        #by how much does this loop affect the run time of Prims?
        for tup in g[b]:
            heapq.heappush(pq, tup)


print weight
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `while pq` loop continues to run long after it needs to. Consider breaking at the bottom of the loop if `len(connected) == n`, assuming your graph is one component.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> #n is the number of nodes m is the number of edges
> n, m = [int(x) for x in raw_input().split(" ")]
> ```

well, instead of writing this comment it would be much better to give your variables meaningful and descriptive names, In this way you won't have to read the comment **and** the variables to know what they are about.

The same applies to `g`, `pq`, `a`.........etc.etc

Comment: yeah, I understand that for n and m. I only used it because  the hackerrank problem used that as its language. pq I agree could be named better to indicate that it's a priorityqueue of the edge weights but I believe using the variable g for naming a generic graph in a graph problem is standard.